# Getting an error when trying to set application icon for Qt project

Tags: qt, icons

I have a project in Qt that has previously been compiled on other machines and the icon works great.

I am running parallels desktop on my macbook and compiling totally under windows (Qt Creator 3.0.1 for windows, Based on Qt 5.2.1 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit)) and when I try to compile I get the following errors:

```
error: error: icon.rc: No such file or directory
warning: '-x c' after last input file has no effect
error: fatal error: no input files
```

Everything else works fine and is identical to compiling on other windows based laptops, I don't think using parallels desktop has anything to do with it because even under bootcamp (booting into windows on the mac) it still gives the same error.

My project file contains:

```
#RC_FILE = icon.rc
#win32:RC_ICONS += icon.ico
win32:RC_FILE += icon.rc
```

None of these versions work to call the icon file.

My icon.rc file looks like:

```
IDI_ICON1               ICON    DISCARDABLE     "icon.ico"
```

The icon.ico and icon.rc are both located in the same folder as all my source code and .pro qt project file.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

I have already had a look at [The Qt Icon Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/appicon.html) and previous posts on the icon topic, none of the suggestions there have worked so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `RC_FILE += $$PWD/icon.rc`.

Comment: @Amartel didn't do the job unfortunately

Comment: I now have it working, however get the following "issues" U:\\PhD\\Programming\\MP512_latest\\icon.rc:1: unrecognized escape sequence
U:\\PhD\\Programming\\MP512_latest\\icon.rc:1: unrecognized escape sequence
U:\\PhD\\Programming\\MP512_latest\\icon.rc:1: unrecognized escape sequence
U:\\PhD\\Programming\\MP512_latest\\icon.rc:1: unrecognized escape sequence